# How to Capture User Signatures on WP7?

Tags: c#, iphone, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmap

[Check this out First thing!!](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/03/25/how-to-capture-user-signatures-on-wp7.aspx)

so this guy posts how to do this on the blog but it doesn't work.
their have been a few people trying to also do the same thing and i know people here could help figure this out.
i did realize because it's WP7, You cant use Bitmap but a derivative from `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` But with this change i cant quit figure out how to Fix this Blog Post and i figured i would turn to this community.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you having trouble saving the strokes as a `Bitmap`?

Comment: yes, i am having an issue with saving it as a Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `WriteableBitmap.Render` method and pass in the canvas as a parameter. Or, use the `InkPresenter` control instead and follow the steps mentioned in [this blog post](http://rongchaua.net/blog/windows-phone-signature-capturing-with-inkpresenter-and-save-to-png-file/).

Comment: Thank you For your help!! it doesn't seem a lot of people help me out on here but i am great full for the ones who do.